# Neo4j - How to display a property on a node, to identify easily in browser?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have a sample graph, where it has two types of nodes, servers and services.
Server and properties looks like:

```
Server:{
"ip":"0.0.1.1"},
"location":"india",
"uptime":"120",
"services":["httpd","IPsec","irqbalance"],
}
```

Where the services is:

```
service:{
"service":"httpd"}
```

My connected graph looks like,[image]

Servers are easily identified with the ip, but the services are not. I want to display service property on node. How to do that?

Comment: A similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/21739837/3966682

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to click on the label (display above the graph) and then choose the property below the graph.

[image]

Neo4j website has a good explanation for this with screenshots: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization

Comment: Pro tip: If you want to edit the styles directly enter `:style` in the console and a modal will pop up

Comment: @Stefan Armbruster : Unable to select, displaying only <id> property down, though it has service property explicitly.