# How to set in the neo4j which attribute is label for a node?

Tags: database, neo4j, attributes, label, cypher

I want do set a specific attribute of a node to be displayed as label in the node instead of another. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Do you mean in the webbroswer display? You can set which node attribute is displayed on the webbrowser. Maybe check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739837/neo4j-2-0-1-browser-display-node-properties-in-addition-to-id-property

Comment: Right, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

in the Neo4j Browser you have to select the Node Label on the top.

[image]

Then you can select the property that you want to display by default , also you can select the size and color that you want to see.

[image]